# servicestack client authentication encrypt password

Tags: c#, .net, api, servicestack

I have Xamarin application that is using servicestack as back-end API the current implementation to authenticate users is sending plain text from client side to server then authenticate users , what i need here two things:

(i) is there a way to encrypt the password on client side using servicestack.client

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
      new IAuthProvider[] { 
        new BasicAuthProvider(), 
        new CredentialsAuthProvider(),credentials
      }));

    Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());

    container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
    var userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
    container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);
}
```

(ii) about login itself - when user login it generates cookies that I cant use in my mobile app. How can I make user use servicestack application without login every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to ensure your password (and everything else) gets sent encrypted is to configure your backend services with SSL so all traffic is sent via https.

An alternative to this is to use ServiceStack's [Encrypted Messaging feature](http://docs.servicestack.net/encrypted-messaging).

In order to populate your Service Client with your Session Id you can save the cookie from an authenticated Service Client with:

```
var ssId = client.GetSessionId();
var sspId = client.GetPermanentSessionId(); //If RememberMe=true
```

And later attach it on a new Service Client with:

```
client.SetSessionId(ssId);
client.SetPermanentSessionId(sspId);
```

Comment: we are working with government client and we are already using SSL but it looks like not enough,  
because the password is still sent from client to server as clear text which make any one with physical access to the mobile client add proxy to fetch device request
through fiddler for example.
 what i need just to encrypt the password only and decrypt it on server without using “encrypted messaging” because it has some complexity’s.

Comment: @moathnaji if you're using SSL/HTTPS it's by definition not sent as clear text and anyone without the SSL cert will not be able to read the traffic. This is the well established standard to encrypt HTTP traffic so I'd recommend investigating into getting it configured properly instead of looking for an ad-hoc bespoke solution